# Enumerated Types in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, scheduled-tasks, enumerated-types

I want to script creating a scheduled task with VBScript.

I need to use the Enumerated Types of the Task Scheduler object to set the task to run with "Highest Privileges".

Anyone know how I set this?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: What API are you using (WMI [Win32_ScheduledJob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394399.aspx) / [schtasks.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357.aspx) / [Task Scheduler Scripting API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383607.aspx)) and which types do you mean? It would help if you added your current code to your post.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using the [Task Scheduler 2.0 Scripting API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383607.aspx), right?

The easiest solution is to manually define any constants needed in your script:

```
Const TASK_RUNLEVEL_LUA     = 0
Const TASK_RUNLEVEL_HIGHEST = 1
```

Alternatively, you can try the following: wrap your VBScript code in a Windows Script (.wsf) file and use the [`<reference>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/479dafxb.aspx) tag to import the Task Scheduler type library, so that your script has access to constants defined in that type library. Your .wsf script would look something like this:

```
<job>
  <reference object="Schedule.Service" />
  <script language="VBScript">
    WScript.Echo TASK_RUNLEVEL_HIGHEST
  </script>
</job>
```

You can find more info on Windows script files here: [Using Windows Script Files (.wsf)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15x4407c.aspx).